# Android program: ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android

I am preparing android application which is showing the following error:

```
03-21 17:30:41.988: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at Newtons.law.background$1.run(background.java:23)
03-21 17:38:56.111: W/dalvikvm(798): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-21 17:38:56.118: E/AndroidRuntime(798): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-99
03-21 17:38:56.118: E/AndroidRuntime(798): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=Newtons.Law.Newton_LawsActivity }
03-21 17:38:56.118: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
03-21 17:38:56.118: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
03-21 17:38:56.118: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
03-21 17:38:56.118: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
03-21 17:38:56.118: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at Newtons.law.background$1.run(background.java:23)
```

my manifest file is as follow in the second activity is showing error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Newtons.law"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".background"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Newton_LawsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Newtons.law.Newton_LawsActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest?  Just to clarify-- there needs to be two activities in there, it looks like Newton_LawsActivity is missing

Comment: @edthethird  i have edited my post with manifest file now plz tell me what is my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActivityNotFoundException it seems you didnt specify it in Android Manifest,

If So then add the activity in manifest, in application tag like this  `<activity android:name=".YourActivity"/>`

Comment: show your code and manifest, if possible in http://pastebin.com/ copy there and paste link here

Answer (score 0):

Add your Activity in **Manifest** file.

Comment: i had added activity in my mainefest file

Answer (score 0):

since i cant find anything about a "newtons.law" on google about android, i would guess from what you are showing, that you are having an ActivityNotFoundException which isnt caught at line 23 of your background.java

maybe you´ve misstyped the name of the activity you want to do whatsoever with in your manifest?

Comment: @edthethird i am not getting you ?

Comment: Intent openAtarNewton_LawsActivity=new Intent(".Newton_LawsActivity");
      startActivity(openAtarNewton_LawsActivity);

Comment: Intent openAtarNewton_LawsActivity=new Intent(".Newton_LawsActivity");
      startActivity(openAtarNewton_LawsActivity); this is my code on the line 23